# Laravel same route in multiple groups and inside multiple controllers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am working on an ecommerce website I have an admin panel as well as seller panel. I have a product module in the admin panel. Actually i want to use the same module in the seller panel also but I want to use the same route for both of the panel. Seller panel is in sub domain and the admin panel is the main domain. I have also provided groups. Is it possible to use the same route with any conditional code without having to use different routes for both admin and seller panels. Please help me out.

**Route File**

```
//Seller Panel
Route::group(['domain' => 'seller.techmart.local'], function () {

    //Login
    Route::any('/', ['uses' => 'Frontend\Seller\Login\LoginController@getLogin', 'as' => 'login']);
    Route::any('/sellerlogin', ['uses' => 'Frontend\Seller\Login\LoginController@ProcessLogin', 'as' => 'sellerlogin']);

    //Dashboard
    Route::any('/seller-dashboard', ['uses' => 'Frontend\Seller\Dashboard\DashboardController@GetIndex', 'as' => 'seller-dashboard']);
});

//Main Domain
Route::group(['domain' => 'techmart.local'], function () {

    //Admin Panel
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'masterpanel', 'middleware' => 'masterpanel'], function() {

        //login
        Route::any('/', ['uses' => 'Admin\LoginController@getLogin', 'as' => 'login']);
        Route::any('processlogin', ['uses' => 'Admin\LoginController@doLogin', 'as' => 'processlogin']);
        Route::any('/logout', ['uses' => 'Admin\LoginController@logout', 'as' => 'logout']);

        //dashboard
        Route::any('dashboard', ['uses' => 'Admin\DashboardController@getDashboard', 'as' => 'dashboard']);

        /********** Category **********/
        Route::any('/brand', ['uses' => 'Brand\BrandController@ManageBrand', 'as' => 'brand']);
        Route::any('/savebrand', ['uses' => 'Brand\BrandController@SaveBrand', 'as' => 'savebrand']);
        Route::any('/viewbrand/{id}', ['uses' => 'Brand\BrandController@ViewBrand', 'as' => 'viewbrand']);
        Route::any('/editbrand/{id}', ['uses' => 'Brand\BrandController@EditBrand', 'as' => 'editbrand']);
        Route::any('/updatebrand', ['uses' => 'Brand\BrandController@UpdateBrand', 'as' => 'updatebrand']);
        Route::any('/deletebrand', ['uses' => 'Brand\BrandController@DeleteBrand', 'as' => 'deletebrand']);
        Route::any('/importbrand', ['uses' => 'Brand\BrandController@ImportBrand', 'as' => 'importbrand']);
        Route::any('/deleteselectedbrand', ['uses' => 'Brand\BrandController@DeleteSelectedBrand', 'as' => 'deleteselectedbrand']);
        Route::any('/deleteallbrand', ['uses' => 'Brand\BrandController@DeleteAllBrand', 'as' => 'deleteallbrand']);

        /********** Product Type **********/
        Route::any('/addproducttype', ['uses' => 'ProductType\ProductTypeController@AddProductType', 'as' => 'addproducttype']);
        Route::any('/saveproducttype', ['uses' => 'ProductType\ProductTypeController@SaveProductType', 'as' => 'saveproducttype']);
        Route::any('/manageproducttype', ['uses' => 'ProductType\ProductTypeController@ManageProductType', 'as' => 'manageproducttype']);
        Route::any('/editproducttype/{id}', ['uses' => 'ProductType\ProductTypeController@EditProductType', 'as' => 'editproducttype']);
        Route::any('/updateproducttype', ['uses' => 'ProductType\ProductTypeController@UpdateProductType', 'as' => 'updateproducttype']);
        Route::any('/deleteproducttype', ['uses' => 'ProductType\ProductTypeController@DeleteProductType', 'as' => 'deleteproducttype']);
        Route::any('/deleteselectedproducttype', ['uses' => 'ProductType\ProductTypeController@DeleteSelectedRecords', 'as' => 'deleteselectedproducttype']);

        /********** Category **********/
        //Category
        Route::any('/category', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@ManageCategory', 'as' => 'category']);
        Route::any('/savecategory', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@SaveCategory', 'as' => 'savecategory']);
        Route::any('/viewcategory/{id}', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@ViewCategory', 'as' => 'viewcategory']);
        Route::any('/editcategory/{id}', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@EditCategory', 'as' => 'editcategory']);
        Route::any('/updatecategory', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@UpdateCategory', 'as' => 'updatecategory']);
        Route::any('/deletecategory', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@DeleteCategory', 'as' => 'deletecategory']);
        Route::any('/deleteselectedcategorylvl1', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@DeleteSelectedCategoryLvl1', 'as' => 'deleteselectedcategorylvl1']);

        Route::any('/view-subcategory-level3-manage', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@ViewSubCategoryLvl3_Manage', 'as' => 'view-subcategory-level3-manage']);
        Route::any('/view-subcategory-level4-manage', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@ViewSubCategoryLvl4_Manage', 'as' => 'view-subcategory-level4-manage']);

        //Sub Category
        Route::any('/category-level2', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@ManageCategoryLvl2', 'as' => 'category-level2']);
        Route::any('/savesubcategory', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@SaveSubCategory', 'as' => 'savesubcategory']);
        Route::any('/viewsubcategory/{id}', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@ViewSubCategory', 'as' => 'viewsubcategory']);
        Route::any('/editsubcategory/{id}', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@EditSubCategory', 'as' => 'editsubcategory']);
        Route::any('/updatesubcategory', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@UpdateSubCategory', 'as' => 'updatesubcategory']);
        Route::any('/deletesubcategory', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@DeleteSubCategory', 'as' => 'deletesubcategory']);
        Route::any('/deleteselectedcategorylvl2', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@DeleteSelectedCategoryLvl2', 'as' => 'deleteselectedcategorylvl2']);

        //Sub Category Lvl3
        Route::any('/category-level3', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@ManageCategoryLvl3', 'as' => 'category-level3']);
        Route::any('/savesubcategorylvl3', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@SaveSubCategoryLvl3', 'as' => 'savesubcategorylvl3']);
        Route::any('/view-subcategory-level3/{id}', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@ViewSubCategoryLvl3', 'as' => 'view-subcategory-level3']);
        Route::any('/edit-subcategory-level3/{id}', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@EditSubCategoryLvl3', 'as' => 'edit-subcategory-level3']);
        Route::any('/updatesubcategorylvl3', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@UpdateSubCategoryLvl3', 'as' => 'updatesubcategorylvl3']);
        Route::any('/deletesubcategorylvl3', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@DeleteSubCategoryLvl3', 'as' => 'deletesubcategorylvl3']);
        Route::any('/deleteselectedcategorylvl3', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@DeleteSelectedCategoryLvl3', 'as' => 'deleteselectedcategorylvl3']);

        //Sub Category Lvl4
        Route::any('/category-level4', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@ManageCategoryLvl4', 'as' => 'category-level4']);
        Route::any('/savesubcategorylvl4', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@SaveSubCategoryLvl4', 'as' => 'savesubcategorylvl4']);
        Route::any('/view-subcategory-level4/{id}', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@ViewSubCategoryLvl4', 'as' => 'view-subcategory-level4']);
        Route::any('/edit-subcategory-level4/{id}', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@EditSubCategoryLvl4', 'as' => 'edit-subcategory-level4']);
        Route::any('/updatesubcategorylvl4', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@UpdateSubCategoryLvl4', 'as' => 'updatesubcategorylvl4']);
        Route::any('/deletesubcategorylvl4', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@DeleteSubCategoryLvl4', 'as' => 'deletesubcategorylvl4']);
        Route::any('/deleteselectedcategorylvl4', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@DeleteSelectedCategoryLvl4', 'as' => 'deleteselectedcategorylvl4']);

        //Import Category
        Route::any('/categoryimport', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@CategoryImport', 'as' => 'categoryimport']);
        Route::any('/importcategorylvl1', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@ImportCategoryLvl1', 'as' => 'importcategorylvl1']);
        Route::any('/importcategorylvl2', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@ImportCategoryLvl2', 'as' => 'importcategorylvl2']);
        Route::any('/importcategorylvl3', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@ImportCategoryLvl3', 'as' => 'importcategorylvl3']);
        Route::any('/importcategorylvl4', ['uses' => 'Category\CategoryController@ImportCategoryLvl4', 'as' => 'importcategorylvl4']);

        /********** Model **********/
        Route::any('/addmodel', ['uses' => 'ModelComponent\ModelController@AddModel', 'as' => 'addmodel']);
        Route::any('/addmodelprocess', ['uses' => 'ModelComponent\ModelController@AddModelProcess', 'as' => 'addmodelprocess']);
        Route::any('/importmodel', ['uses' => 'ModelComponent\ModelController@ImportModel', 'as' => 'importmodel']);
        Route::any('/importmodelprocess', ['uses' => 'ModelComponent\ModelController@ImportModelProcess', 'as' => 'importmodelprocess']);
        Route::any('/managemodel', ['uses' => 'ModelComponent\ModelController@ManageModel', 'as' => 'managemodel']);
        Route::any('/editmodel/{id}', ['uses' => 'ModelComponent\ModelController@EditModel', 'as' => 'editmodel']);
        Route::any('/updatemodel', ['uses' => 'ModelComponent\ModelController@UpdateModel', 'as' => 'updatemodel']);
        Route::any('/deletemodel', ['uses' => 'ModelComponent\ModelController@DeleteModel', 'as' => 'deletemodel']);
        Route::any('/deleteselectedmodel', ['uses' => 'ModelComponent\ModelController@DeleteSelectedModel', 'as' => 'deleteselectedmodel']);

        /********** Tech Specs **********/
        Route::any('/addtechspecsformat', ['uses' => 'TechSpecs\TechSpecsController@AddSpecsFormat', 'as' => 'addtechspecsformat']);
        Route::any('/addtechspecsformatprocess', ['uses' => 'TechSpecs\TechSpecsController@AddSpecsFormatProcess', 'as' => 'addtechspecsformatprocess']);
        Route::any('/specsgetmodel', ['uses' => 'TechSpecs\TechSpecsController@GetModel', 'as' => 'specsgetmodel']);


        Route::any('/managespecsformat', ['uses' => 'TechSpecs\TechSpecsController@ManageSpecsFormat', 'as' => 'managespecsformat']);
        Route::any('/viewspecsformat', ['uses' => 'TechSpecs\TechSpecsController@ViewSpecsFormat', 'as' => 'viewspecsformat']);
        Route::any('/editspecsformat/{id}', ['uses' => 'TechSpecs\TechSpecsController@EditSpecsFormat', 'as' => 'editspecsformat']);
        Route::any('/deletespecsformat', ['uses' => 'TechSpecs\TechSpecsController@DeleteSpecsFormat', 'as' => 'deletespecsformat']);
        Route::any('/deleteselectedformat', ['uses' => 'TechSpecs\TechSpecsController@DeleteSelectedSpecsFormat', 'as' => 'deleteselectedformat']);


        /********** Products **********/
        Route::any('/products', ['uses' => 'Products\ProductController@ManageProducts', 'as' => 'products']);
        Route::any('/saveproduct', ['uses' => 'Products\ProductController@SaveProduct', 'as' => 'saveproduct']);
        Route::any('/viewproduct/{id}', ['uses' => 'Products\ProductController@ViewProduct', 'as' => 'viewproduct']);
        Route::any('/editproduct/{id}', ['uses' => 'Products\ProductController@EditProduct', 'as' => 'editproduct']);
        Route::any('/updateproduct', ['uses' => 'Products\ProductController@UpdateProduct', 'as' => 'updateproduct']);
        Route::any('/deleteproduct', ['uses' => 'Products\ProductController@DeleteProduct', 'as' => 'deleteproduct']);

        Route::any('/productsgetbrand', ['uses' => 'Products\ProductController@ProductsGetBrandDetails', 'as' => 'productsgetbrand']);
        Route::any('/productgetsku', ['uses' => 'Products\ProductController@GetSKU', 'as' => 'productgetsku']);
        //Route::any('/getselectedproductcat', ['uses' => 'Products\ProductController@GetSelectedProdCat', 'as' => 'getselectedproductcat']);

        Route::any('/productscategory', ['uses' => 'Products\ProductController@GetCategory', 'as' => 'productscategory']);
        Route::any('/productsgetmodel', ['uses' => 'Products\ProductController@GetModel', 'as' => 'productsgetmodel']);
        Route::any('/productgettechspecs', ['uses' => 'Products\ProductController@ProductGetSpecs', 'as' => 'productgettechspecs']);
        Route::any('/deleteselectedproducts', ['uses' => 'Products\ProductController@DeleteSelectedRecords', 'as' => 'deleteselectedproducts']);

        /********** Attribute **********/
        //Attribute
        Route::any('/attribute', ['uses' => 'Attribute\AttributeController@ManageAttributes', 'as' => 'attribute']);
        Route::any('/save-attribute-set', ['uses' => 'Attribute\AttributeController@SaveAttributeSet', 'as' => 'save-attribute-set']);
        Route::any('/save-attribute', ['uses' => 'Attribute\AttributeController@SaveAttribute', 'as' => 'save-attribute']);

    });

    //Scraper
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'vendorpanel', 'middleware' => 'vendorpanel'], function() {

        //Login
        Route::any('/', ['uses' => 'Scraper\ScraperController@getLogin', 'as' => 'login']);
        Route::any('processlogin-scraper', ['uses' => 'Scraper\ScraperController@doLogin', 'as' => 'processlogin-scraper']);

        //dashboard
        Route::any('vendor-dashboard', ['uses' => 'Scraper\ScraperController@getDashboard', 'as' => 'vendor-dashboard']);
        Route::any('/logout-vendor', ['uses' => 'Scraper\ScraperController@logout', 'as' => 'logout-vendor']);

        //Scraping
        Route::any('/process-scraping', ['uses' => 'Scraper\ScraperController@doScraping', 'as' => 'process-scraping']);

    });

    //Frontend
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('frontend.welcome');
    });

});
```

Comment: if you want use same route both parties then you have to control return **view or data** from **controller function** using seller type or admin type if am wrong clarify your question with important codes not all

Comment: @Hamelraj From what you are saying is i should make change in controller right?

Comment: yes you have to

Comment: Ok but the main issue is I am using different Controllers. So how can i achieve it then that way

Comment: You can go about having same route for both users. But, in future, if you wish to add functionalities only to admins then you might have to heavily add `@if admin` logic to the common views.

I'm not sure on why you want to have same controller for two different stakeholders. It's a good practise to separate controllers and maintain one for each. I'm sure there will be a point where you would want to access or add features to only admins/sellers.

Comment: @HariHarker ok will try that. Thanks.